# Context.User.Identity.Name vs HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Tags: asp.net, session, forms-authentication

In aspx.net, what is the difference between

```
Context.User.Identity.Name
```

and

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Im currently using the `Context.User.Identity.Name` from a masterpage and are having trouble with user identitys beeing mixed up (user A sees user B data). Could this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are identical. `Context` has a reference to the current `HttpContext` which is the same as `HttpContext.Current`. So, I don't think this is causing the problem that you are having.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i know the two methods are identical because

```
Context
```

is the same as

```
HttpContext.Current
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in the context of a Page, because [Page.Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.context.aspx) returns the current [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx).

[HttpContext.Current](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx) is a static method that returns the HttpContext
associated with the calling thread (may return null)
Page.Context is a reference set to same object as HttpContext.Current, but
is a direct reference, no internal lookup required.